# Access methods from Java project in Jython

Tags: java, scripting, jython

I'm currently coding a game in Java that is growing bigger over time.
So now I'm at a point where more dynamic implementations of code would become quite handy.
I decided to take a look into Jython and got it working with some simple scripts already.
(Btw I'm using the newest standalone Jython if it matters somehow).

**Now my Question is:** Can I execute methods that are in my Java project in a Jython script that is executed in the mentioned Java project?

Here is an example of pseudo-code for better understanding what I want to ask:

Let's say I have a Script that looks like the following:

```
def main():
    killPlayer()

main()
```

And a Java class that contains the method "killPlayer()":

```
public void killPlayer() {
    player.setAlive(false);
}
```

While the Jython script is executed as following:

```
PythonInterpreter pyInterp = new PythonInterpreter();
pyInterp("script.py");
```

Is anything of that kind possible?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import Java classes in Jython like so:

```
from javax.swing import JFrame
f = JFrame('Hello, World!', defaultCloseOperation=JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, size=(300, 300), locationRelativeTo=None)
f.setVisible(True)
```

([source](https://wiki.python.org/jython/SwingExamples))

So my suggestion is to use the Java code as a library and implement the "setup everything" in Python. That way, you won't need to figure out a way to look up instances of Java objects from the script.

If you need to look up instances, I suggest to create a static global variable somewhere which gives you access to a class that exposes important game instances. In the Java code, you can then register the instances with a name in a `Map` for the Jython scripts.

Comment: Thanks! I did not expect that I could import my own packages and classes that easily.